# How to find out what's under the hood of the CLR function

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, clr, sqlclr

The server that I serve has many CLR objects. This is my first encounter with them. Perhaps they do not work correctly, and optimization is needed. There is no source code. How can I find out the code of these objects? They are probably written in C#. I tried to run the profiler, but except for the "EXEC 'Name Of Clr object'" I did not see it. As I guess, this is about disassembling a DLL file?

Comment: Not much point tagging SQL Server and ADO.NET for a disassembly problem.

Comment: If you don't have the source, how were the objects created in the first place? What happens if you discover that there's a bug?